# Web-Scrape Results Not coming Back as Intended

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

## The Issue

No results in the 2nd stage when running

### The code

```
  print("========Stage One========")
  url = url_string
  page = requests.get(url)
  soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser') # Payload 2 soup value

  results = soup2.find(id='list-container')
  print(results.prettify())
  print('========Stage Two========')
  resultSections = results.find_all(class_='mobile-frame pull-left')
  for resultSection in resultSections:
    print(resultSection)
    print("+"*10)
```

### What did I expect/want?

- To Get HTML based on Class name (Achieved in stage one but not in stage 2)
- Have information Sectioned Off per divider (`<div class="">`)

### What did I get?

In terms of what I got back after running this script was half of what I expected.

Stage One Worked as intended however Stage Two returned neither results or an error as seen here:

[image: Result Image]

### What I tried

In terms of what things I tried included the following methods:

```
results.find_all(div, class_='mobile-frame pull-left') #Current
```

And

```
results.find(div, class_='mobile-frame pull-left') # Gives Error
```

Comment: can you please post the url you are scraping and the sample lines from there, you want in your output?

Comment: I will post what Info I can in order to help, I will make sure to update the question with additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found the solution to my problem.

It appears it gave me the browser emulated page for mobile rather then the computer site.

Refreshing the site gave me the class name of `col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6` which I then used to replace `mobile-frame pull-left`

Doing this resulted in the desired data.